# Increment Table Name Based on Current Date

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, powerquery

I am trying to add a table into my power bi using the SQL Server data source. The thing is that a new table is added daily with the format of the year `YYMMDD`. Example: `MYTABLE191121`, tomorrow it will be `MYTABLE191122`.

How can i write a query in Power BI that always looks at the latest table based on today's date? I want to be able to refresh the content and have latest table's data.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If your database name is `TEST_DB` on `localhost` your query can be like this:

```
let
    Source = Sql.Databases("localhost"),
    TEST_DB = Source{[Name="TEST_DB"]}[Data],

    // chain a few functions to create today's date in YYMMDD
    TODAYS_DATE = Text.Range(Text.Remove(Date.ToText(DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow())),"-"),2),

    // simply use & to concat MYTABLE and today's date 
    todays_table = TEST_DB{[Schema="dbo",Item="MYTABLE" & TODAYS_DATE]}[Data]
in
    todays_table
```

This will create a query like this: `SELECT * FROM [dbo].[MYTABLE191122]` into the table `todays_table`.